# What happens when someone does too many crunches?

Tags: abdominals

If someone basically only do crunches (or other exercises with a similar contraction) for his abs (many people seem to be in this group), what would be the result? Would this be unhealthy? Should I complement them with other exercises?

Comment: Define "too many".

Comment: Take a look at the work of Dr Stuart McGill and his take on ab training, specifically crunches.

Answer (score 3):

**If someone basically only do crunches (or other exercises with a similar contraction) for his abs (many people seem to be in this group), what would be the result?**

You would get good at doing lots of crunches.

**Would this be unhealthy?**

Maybe, might want to use a small mat to protect your lower spine form the floor. If you manage to keep the high volume of just crunches up your will get developed abs but nothing else. Your back will be 'over-powered' by your core and you will hunch over, causing back issues long-term.

**Should I complement them with other exercises?**

Of course you should.

Comment: Probably not unhealthy? I'd say only doing crunches will mess up you'd posture big time, which I wouldn't consider healthy.

Comment: Fair point, modified answer.